# Install python dependency only when platform is Windows

Tags: python-2.7, dependencies, setuptools

I want to add `pywin32` as **Conditional Python Dependencies** to `setup.py` when `platform_system == Windows`

Could anyone give me a hint on how to make it work?

After exploring the stackoverflow, haven't found a answer to python2.7.

I'm using Python 2.7, setuptools 28.x.x, pip 19.x.x. Egg-info is auto-build.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import platform

platform_system = platform.system()

setup(
    name=xxx,
    version=xxx,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'matplotlib',
    ],
    extras_require={
        'platform_system=="Windows"': [
            'pywin32'
        ]
    },
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        xx:xx
    ''',
)
```

I don't understand how the keys in `extras_require` work. Would `platform_system` refer to the definition of `platform_system` in the front?

I also tried:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import platform

setup(
    xxx
    install_requires=[
        'matplotlib',
        'pywin32;platform_system=="Windows"',
    ],
)
```

But this is available only for `python_version>=3.4`

Also, it looks like https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/ doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check Python [os](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.name) module

`os.name`
The name of the operating system dependent module imported. The following names have currently been registered: 'posix', 'nt', 'os2', 'ce', 'java', 'riscos'.

and **nt** uses for windows OS.

```py
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    # Windows-specific code here...
```

You can check [sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.platform) too.

`sys.platform`
This string contains a platform identifier that can be used to append platform-specific components to sys.path, for instance.

```py
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    # Windows-specific code here...
```

**Edited:**
base on your question, you want to install pywin32 if OS is Windows.
I think this code will help you:

```py
import sys


INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    # ...
]
EXTRAS_REQUIRE = {
    # ...
}

if sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    INSTALL_REQUIRES.append("pywin32")

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    extras_require=EXTRAS_REQUIRE,
)
```

Comment: Does if statements work with setup? Could you please give my a setup example?

Comment: If that's true, please check my answer. @shinyshinx

Answer (score 2):

You can use Environment Markers in the specification of your dependencies.
See [PEP 508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers).

For detecting if the operating system is Windows or not, you can use `os_name` being equal to `nt`.

Based on the syntax in the PEP which shows  `"name; os_name=='a' or os_name=='b'"`, your install_requires section can be:

```
install_requires=[
    "matplotlib",
    "pywin32; os_name=='nt'",
],
```

There is no need to use `extras_require` for this.